# How do I model Application specific Roles in Claims

Tags: claims-based-identity, identityserver3

We have a central UserManagerApplication that manage users and roles for multiple application. In this application we typically set that

- UserA is in role Admin for Application1
- UserA is in role Reader for Application2

Problem: When Application2 request a scope (say scopeApp1) that includes Roles, both Reader and Admin roles claim will be returned as they are filtered on claimtypes and not scope.

Question: How can I request only a subset of the Roles?

We use a custom userservice, and from my understanding the place I could filter out the returned claims are in this method, and I cant find a way to figure out what scope the client requested:

```
public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
```

As far as I can see my options are:

- Include ApplicationName included in the role (App1Admin, App2Reader etc)
- Create a new ClaimType for each application. App1Role, App2Role
- I've missed something obvious and need to get a better understanding

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: The context should have the client ID.

Comment: @leastprivilege thanks. I've added an answer so the question could be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pointed to a good read at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/474 that describes the problem.

In addition I was adding the claims in the CustomUserService where the scopes are not availible. When I instead add the claims in a custom ClaimsProvider i get a slightly different signature

```
 public override async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync(ClaimsPrincipal subject, Client client, IEnumerable<Scope> scopes, ValidatedRequest request)
```

That lets me figure out the requested scopes.